# select categories and subcategories and the sub of subcategories (multidimensional view)

Tags: php, mysql

how to select categories and subcategories and the multi sub categories by mysql query ?
like this:

```
Main category 1
   category 1
   category 2
      category 3
      category 4
         category 5
Main category 2
   category 6
   category 7
      category 8
      category 9
         category 10
```

I tried this code but it does not work

```
$cats = mysqli_query($con, "select id,name from categories order by id ASC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($cats)){
    $a[$row['name']] = $row;
    $has_sub = mysqli_query($con, "select id,name from categories where parent_id=".$row['id']);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($has_sub)>0)
        $a[$row['name']]['sub'] = mysqli_fetch_array($has_sub);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to post the code you have tried so far. Your current question is unclear and the problem is not reproducible. We encourage you to research first and design some code. Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to know how to frame a question.

Comment: the code added above

Comment: my question is clear, I want to get a tree view of all categories

Comment: With a single table design like yours, with arbitrary levels of nested categories, you will need to use a recursive function to get all the levels. Executing queries recursively will have a great performance cost. Depending on your needs, it may be better to alter your database and only allow for a limited level of nested categories in separate tables that you could join together to get this result much more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late to answer, but for anyone who still search for this:
You can use recursive queries with `WITH` keyword in MySQL to do such things